# Setting up a hour tracker in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application based on the [Devise cancan](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan) repo.

What I want to add is a way for users to choose a day, log a set amount of hours for that day, choose a project to tie those hours to, and say what they did. How can I go about doing this in the simplest way. Possibly using any helpful gems as well.

Comment: Please post some code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thats the thing, I know a bit of ruby and rails but im new with building apps and I have no clue where to start when it comes to adding functionality on top of the current application.

Comment: SO is not a forum for generic, step-by-step how-to. You're better off reading the Rails documentation, or any of the canonical books by DHH (much of which will explain _nearly_ exactly how to do what you're seeking to accomplish). What you're asking for here is beyond the scope of what a poster can answer in a single post.

Comment: Well, I gave it a shot anyways. I applaud your effort to gain an understanding for Rails using the Devise repo – it's a good one. The process is actually quite simple, even for a novice. Hopefully the answer below can get you started.

Comment: Thank you, there is just so much out there that it gets hard to find what you need. But I will check out your resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a mix of actual code and pseudo-code that might get you started:

Create a schedule and project resource from the command line:

```
rails g resource log day:date duration:float description:string
rails g resource project title:string
```

Associate `Log` with `User`, and `Project` with `Log`:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :logs

# app/models/log.rb
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :projects
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :log
end
```

That should give you the general association framework to get started. Then, build out your views such that a user is displayed with a form to create a log. Use the [`date_select` DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) to create a date dropdown. Create a dropdown of all projects using [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) on `Project.all`. Then, in your controller, you should be able to do something like this:

```
# app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ActionController

    def create
        project = Product.new(params[:project])
        if project.save
            current_user << project
            ...
        else
            ...
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: All that's missing is the views code, which shouldn't be terribly difficult to piece together from the docs. Feel free to update your question with some code should you run into any trouble – it's exponentially easier to help debug if you can document what you've tried.